# Insert special characters into table name

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have an Android application. When I create a new table, if I add a special character like `!` or `$`, the application crashes. I have created the functionality to replace an spaces with an `_` like so:

```
String name = name.getText().toString().replace(" ", "_");

// execute my insert query here
```

How can I do the same for any other special character other than space when I create a new table? Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: Smells like you have a database design problem if the database table name is based on user input.

Comment: The user creates a new list of data and a table is generated for that list which is why user input is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use This:

```
String name = "Table$Name";
name = name.replaceAll("\\W", "_");
```

Comment: All special characters.

Comment: Thankyou very much Amy! This works just fine! I will accept this answer!

Comment: Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 3):

You can escape special characters in a string using an inbuilt function in Android. Like below,

```
String name = DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(name.getText().toString())
```

Comment: Thankyou Santhosh! I think your answer is working better because it displays the characters in my `RecyclerView` rather than replacing them entirely.

Comment: @SvenRonnlund thats better but your question is wrong you are asking for replacing the character. I thought its business need. :)

Comment: @Amy you are spot on :) I felt the opposite and thought that he needs to know both the options to decide

Comment: Ya Its ok santosh be careful while asking the question.

Comment: I think that was my fault that I wasn't clear enough. I will choose Amy's answer because it replaces any special character but this answer would have also been accepted because it actually displays the characters in my `RecyclerView` rather than replacing them completely. I apologise to you both for any confusions.

Comment: Personally, I think this should of been the accepted answer.